# dpkg -p is not working for some packages (like vim)

Tags: dpkg

I am studying for LPIC exam and one of the tasks in the lab is to find details about package with `dpkg -p`, concretely about *vim* with `dpkg -p vim`. In the solution, the command produces information about the package, but my output is:

```bsh
root@home:~# dpkg -p vim
dpkg-query: package 'vim' is not available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

*Vim* is installed, I am using it offen and it can also be found on system

```bsh
root@home:~# type vim
vim is hashed (/usr/bin/vim)
root@home:~# which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

I thought the `dpkg -p` is somehow broken, but it works with other packages (I have tried several and they all worked fine):

```bsh
root@home:~# dpkg -p eject
Package: eject
Priority: important
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 160
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
...
```

My system (VPS) info is

```
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Linux 4.15.0-143-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 16:10:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Why can I not reproduce the solution from the course? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a distant time, `dpkg` wasn't used by `apt` which didn't exist yet but by other front-ends, like `dselect`. Those tools took care of updating the available list of packages which ends in the file `/var/lib/dpkg/available` eg when running `dselect update`. `dpkg -p`'s feature depends on an up to date available list file.

That's not always the case today. `apt` doesn't care about `/var/lib/dpkg/available` at all. There might be other (possibly GUI) tools that still get this file updated somehow, and thus `/var/lib/dpkg/available` might be partially filled-in.

The manpage for [`dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dpkg.1.html) (or `dpkg-query`) tells:

> `-p`, `--print-avail` package-name...
>
> Display details about package-name, as found in
> `/var/lib/dpkg/available`. **Users of APT-based frontends should use
> `apt-cache show package-name` instead**.

There's also:

> `--update-avail` [Packages-file]
> `--merge-avail` [Packages-file]
>
> Update *dpkg*'s and *dselect*'s idea of  which  packages  are
> available.  With  action `--merge-avail`, old  information is combined
> with information from Packages-file. With action `--update-avail`, old
> information is replaced with the information in the Packages-file. The
> Packages-file distributed with Debian is simply named «Packages». If
> the Packages-file argument is missing or named «-» then it will be
> read  from  standard input (since dpkg 1.17.7). *dpkg* keeps its
> record of available packages in `/var/lib/dpkg/available`.

You can use [`apt-cache dumpavail`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-cache.8.html) to generate on-the-fly an available file format output:

> `dumpavail`
> dumpavail prints out an available list to stdout. This is suitable for use with dpkg(1) and is used by the dselect(1) method.

And merge the result (this example wasn't run on Ubuntu):

```
# apt-cache dumpavail | dpkg --merge-avail -
Updating available packages info, using -.
Information about 119859 packages was updated.
```

`dpkg -p vim` will now work, but it would have probably been simpler to use directly `apt-cache show vim` or `apt show vim`.

Conclusion: some LPIC questions are probably outdated, but to get your exam, you'll have to learn specific exam things that aren't used anywhere anymore.

Comment: Note that I don't know if the *vim* package is *installed* rather than *available* in OP's case but this doesn't change this. There are several packages providing the `vim` packages (in addition of `vim` itself). Try `apt-cache showpkg vim` to get a list of packages that can provide `vim` (eg: vim-nox, vim-gtk3, vim-gtk, vim-athena)

Comment: +1. This is why I still use `dselect update`, but with `apt install` or `apt dist-upgrade`.   Also because I never use `dselect` for anything else any more so I can just type `!dsel`  to take advantage of bash's history.